# Regex to select everything in between two characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a regex that will select the data between two characters (& - @).

```
& foo @
```

I would like to select **foo**.

Any ideas? Good explanations are also appreciated.

Comment: maybe you want `^&.@$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

`preg_match('~&([^@]*)@~',$content,$match);`